# PowerEdge 1955 Blade Switches - PowerConnect 5316m

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell-powerconnect

I currently working on a project to expand my companies storage while virtualizing our infrastructure. One road block I'm running into at the moment is trying to figure out conceptually how the blade switches work and also how to access their management console (ideally through web interface).

Someone before me set them up and I'm not sure exactly how to go about accessing the OpenManage interface. I have documentation saying that they were given an IP address so they should be setup for the web interface. I have tried connecting via ethernet directly to the switch, giving it an IP address on the correct subnet, tried connecting via web interface through the DRAC/MC nothing.

There is very little documentation out there on how to go about this and I was wondering if anyone here has any idea where I can go next.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you described, the next/first logical step is to console in through the serial console port. The unit appears to be a rebranded Cisco 3030 switch, so the standard Cisco rollover console cable should get you serial access.

Comment: I was able to get into the switch that is on our lan. However, the other networks for data I haven't had as much luck.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your last sentence???